# How to change the background color of Button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have following code, I'm using to display my custom dialog box. But the the color of button is by default gray. How do I add background color and increase or decrease it's size or make it round in javascript.

```
document.getElementById('dialog-box-foot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
```

Comment: All that can be done with CSS. No JavaScript necessary.

Comment: as ryan said it's just styling... If you want it set when you click the button though then just set a style property with the innerhtml... so <button style=[style options]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, is this what you are looking for:

```js
document.getElementById('dialog-box-foot').innerHTML = "<button class='mybtn' onclick=\"alert(\'ok\')\">OK</button>";
```

```css
.mybtn{
 background:#00f;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.mybtn:hover{
 background:#0f0;
}
.mybtn:active{
 background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-box-foot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can change the background color or size:

```
        document.getElementById("mybutton").style.background='#000000';
         // size
        document.getElementById("mybutton").style.height='50px';
        document.getElementById("mybutton").style.width='50px';
        // radious
        document.getElementById("mybutton").style.borderRadius = "25px";
```

Comment: How do I set the Id for button?

Comment: @BluePanda <button id=mybutton>

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the CSS of your element:

```
#dialog-box-foot {
    background-color: #ee6e73;  // Background color
    border-radius: 4px;         // Round
    font-size: 16px;            // Font size
}
```

Here you can find some example : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I only want to change the background of button not the whole footer below.

Comment: It the footer change colors its because you give it the same ID. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('dialog-box-foot')
//While inserting
elem.innerHTML = '<button style="background:yellow;height:30px;width:30px;border-radius:50%;" onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';

//After inserting
var buttonelem = document.getElementById('buttonelem');
buttonelem.style.background = "aliceblue";
buttonelem.style.height = "50px";
buttonelem.style.width = "50px";
buttonelem.style.borderRadius = "50%";
```

```html
<div id="dialog-box-foot"></div>
<button id="buttonelem">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple `css` style , you can try this .
  get advantage of `cssText` property .

```
  document.getElementById("dialog-box-foot").style.cssText = "background-color:#f00;left:10%;top:30%";
```